# Entering into form with Mechanize

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, form-submit

Im writing a smaller part of a larger program that is using mechanize to input a YouTube URL into a form but i cant get it to work

Im using the first form on the page `nr=0` but i don't what to put in the `br[]` attribute box since i don't have the name of the form just the id

Here is my code:

```
import mechanize

url = "Youtube to Mp3 URL"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br[?] = "Youtube Video URL" #What goes in the []?
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
print content
```

Im sure its  a dumb question but none of the other questions are helping me

Thank You!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get a field in the form ? If that is the case you can try with a loop, `for field in br.select_form():` Or at least use the for to print the name of each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following and works:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
for field_name in br.form.controls:
    print field_name
```

that will give you a clue of the name of the field you need to fill out, it will be on a parentheses like the following:

```
<HiddenControl(submit_hidden=submit_hidden) (readonly)>
<TextControl(user_name=)>
<PasswordControl(user_password=)>
<SubmitControl(submit=Login) (readonly)>
```

in this case the fields are **user_name** and **user_password**

this is what worked for me, but as I told you the Download link comes in Javascript and mechanize does not support it, you will need something like [WATIR](http://watir.com/) which is for ruby.

```
   browser.select_form(nr=0)

   for field in browser.form.controls:
       field._value = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARz8ddGIZIA"
       break

   browser.submit()
   response = browser.response().read()
```

Comment: `<TextControl(<None>=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Convert Video) (disabled, readonly)>`Thats what i get?

Comment: Well looks like the form has no names to it.

Comment: then how do i enter into them!?

Comment: If you share the url that you are trying to browse maybe I can figure something out.

Comment: I figure out a way to submit the form with a youtube url, the problem  now is that you will need javascript to download the video, and mechanize does not support it. I updated my answer.

Comment: ill try it and i dont need javascript to download it i just parse out the download url and use urlretrieve